Using GmailApp.sendEmail() in Google Apps Script paired with google sheet. not receiving and seemingly sending emails
As the title states I'm trying to email data from a sheet but i'm not receiving any emails. I'm using an edit trigger to run the following:
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart != 4 || e.value > 7) return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getValues();
  let maintItem = rData[0][0];
  let daysLeft = rData[0][4]
  let procedure = rData[0][5];
  let link = rData[0][6];

  let msg = maintItem + " Requires maintenance in " + daysLeft + " days." + "\n This is what you need to do: " + "\n"+ procedure + "\n" + "Helpful information:\n" + link;

  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com",maintItem + " requires maintenance.",msg);
}

I don't get any errors and the executions tab states it's "Completed" but I don't see anything in the logs (I've tried adding Logger.log("Test") and haven't seen anything either.
I've tried using MailApp(same inside)
I've tried using MailApp({bcc: MyEmail, subject: "test", html+: "test",});

This is working for me:
Using installable onEdit()
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  if(e.range.columnStart != 4 || Number(e.value) > 7) return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate1");
  const [maintItem,,,,daysLeft,procedure,link] = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1,7).getValues().flat();
  let msg = maintItem + " Requires maintenance in " + daysLeft + " days." + "\n This is what you need to do: " + "\n"+ procedure + "\n" + "Helpful information:\n" + link;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv,maintItem + " requires maintenance.",msg);
}

This is my data:




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
COL1
COL2
COL3
COL4
COL5
COL6
COL7


2
9
19
17
6
24
14
22



This is my email contents:
9 Requires maintenance in 24 days.
 This is what you need to do:
14
Helpful information:
22

